# How can I get controller value in metadata tag?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to call variable from controller in metadata tag using angularjs and my process is:

In controller,

```
app.controller('homeCtlr', function($scope){

    $scope.test ="MetaTag";

});
```

In HTML,

```
<head>
    <meta name="test" content="{{test}}" />
</head>
```

and pass this value in angular route provider,

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home',
        {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtlr',
            test:'{{test}}',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/home'
        })
})
```

How to get controller value in meta tag and pass this value when using angular routing.

Comment: placing that value in `$rootScope` would be an better option here..

Comment: Your scope level variable is only visible within where the controller is defined in your html markup. Your <head> is not within your homeCtrl nor within your app for that matter. even rootScope wont work there.

Comment: @RiceJunkie you are making assumptions on app scope, if `ng-app` is on `<html>` tag, `$rootScope` certainly is available

Comment: true. I guess the lack of his/her html mark up led me to that. if app and controller were defined on <html> then even $scope would be available

Comment: With a quick look: `test:'{{test}}'` is totally wrong, double mustache syntax is to be used in html markup, not as JS object property value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define your app and your controller on your html like this

```html
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
```